# mod_rewrite: check if isn't a certain domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm migrating some code from a working web app, but can't get it to work on the new server. Everything seems to be configured correctly, but I'm getting internal redirect limit errors in Apache2. Here are my rewrites and explanation

This WORKS - any subdomains that aren't cdn. or manage. should be redirected to u.php

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(^.*)\.mediasprk\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond ^(.*)$ !^(cdn|manage)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(png|gif|jpg)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ u.php?uri=$1&hostName=%{HTTP_HOST}
```

This is no longer working. Goal here is to handle CName pointing. So if it's not my app domain (mediasprk.com), then handle it by sending it to u.php.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^mediasprk\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI) !\.(png|gif|jpg)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ u.php?uri=$1&hostName=%{HTTP_HOST}
```

Can anyone see the issue here in the second block that would cause the redirect limit errors? Maybe something wrong in the rewrites? Thanks.

Comment: Addition: both of these are in the same htaccess - i'm not presenting an either/or - i need both to work, or be consolidated somehow. I suck at rewrites! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I can see two problems here. Firstly, I don't believe your first RewriteCond directive is valid and meaningful:

```
RewriteCond ^(.*)$ !^(cdn|manage)$
```

See the [section about RewriteCond in the Apache manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond).

Secondly, you're getting infinite rewrites because your second block of rules is using the HTTP_HOST value (the domain name) as the test condition, but fails to modify the HTTP_HOST value. In other words, if the RewriteCond test matches (and the domain name is not "mediasprk.com") then the RewriteRule is simply telling Apache to change the path to something different on the same domain. And what most people don't realise is that rewritten paths *have to go through the mod_rewrite rules from the top*. So the rewritten path will stay on whatever domain the initial request was using, which means the RewriteCond will match again, and the rewrite will happen again. And then again. And so on until you get a server error telling you the rewrite limit has been reached.

You can break out of this loop by changing the RewriteRule to:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mediasprk.com/u.php?uri=$1&hostName=%{HTTP_HOST}
```

but this will cause a browser redirect rather than a silent rewrite.

The other way to break out of the infinite loop is to check that the request is not already asking for the u.php file, so you could add an extra RewriteCond before that RewriteRule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/u\.php$
```

Either way, you need to make it possible to break out of the infinite loop which your current directives create.